# Expression in ng-if of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following snippet

**ng-if not working**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="bigL in bigLs">
                <span ng-if="isObj(bigL)">{{bigL.note}}</span>
                <ul ng-if="bigL instanceof Array">
                    <li ng-repeat="bigLl in bigL">
                        {{bigLl}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ng-if working**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="bigL in bigLs">
                <span ng-if="isObj(bigL)">{{bigL.note}}</span>
                <ul ng-if="isArr(bigL)">
                    <li ng-repeat="bigLl in bigL">
                        {{bigLl}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.isArr = function(bigL){
        return bigL instanceof Array;
};
```

I use ng-if to determine whether a nested ul is required to create (by determinate different data type inside the array **bigLs**), I come to a situation that ng-if cannot evaluate **bigL instanceof Array**, I then move this snippet inside a function, with the same context, the ng-of works properly, but still cannot understand why it is a need to wrap the expression inside a function instead of running it directly inside the ng-if.

Appreciate for any clarification, thanks!

Comment: AngularJS expression syntax is NOT pure Javascript.  There is a tremendous amount that it cannot and will not parse and execute.

Comment: Thanks for the clarify, so if I want to do the logic in pure javascript, wrapping it inside a function is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of the problem, but there are several things that have bad smells in your code:

Don't use 'instanceof Array', ever. It won't work in an angular expression.

Instead, use angular.isArray().  This will only work in javascript by adding a method to your scope.

So, you would want to do something like this:

Controller:

```
...
$scope.hasChildren = function(bigL1) {
  return angular.isArray(bigL1);
}
```

Template:

```
 ...
 <ul ng-if="hasChildren(bigL)">
 ...
```

As a bonus, it becomes much easier to unit test this code.